# action can't be completed cause file is open in oracleserviceorcl

Tags: oracle

I want to delete the files I installed of oracle but it says action can't be completed cause file is open in oracleserviceorcl .
is there a way to delete it ?

Answer (score 1):

So stop the service. You'll find it in the Windows Services control panel. You'll probably have other Oracle* services that will need to be stopped as well.  And since you appear to want to un-install Oracle, you'll also need to delete some entries from the Windows registry, as well as the Oracle inventory files, which are located somewhere under C:\Program Files (I don't have a Windows installation handy to check).

But if this is your goal, why not use the Oracle uninstaller?  See the documentation at https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/ntdbi/removing-oracle-database-software.html#GUID-1423C1B2-5501-48AE-BE57-CFDF96290F6C

Answer (score 0):

Try to stop running files of Oracle from Task Manager. It worked for me.